# Sharing webpages without the use of subdomains

Tags: url, subdomain

I'm currently working on a site that shows results which'pop up'. It's still on the same page, this means we can't share it via url since those are all the same. Check out the current Beta to understand what I mean. www.wheretrip.com/prelaunch. We use node.js with sockets for the backend, and javascript for most of the frontend. 
So if people want to share the trip they found to Spain on a certain date for example, this can't be shared.

Does someone knows a way this problem could be solved?

Kind regards,

Sando

Comment: So we´re talking about a SinglePageApplication (SPA) here?
This sure is a problem, which in my opinion could be adressed with Frameworks like [Angular](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) / [React](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) - especially "URL routing" is the keyword to further look for.

Comment: What do you mean with subdomain exactly? Seems you don’t refer to its meaning as in `http://SUBDOMAIN.example.com/path`.